# Trigger a prompt when any user runs a specific command

Tags: rhel, oracle-linux

Working on Oracle Linux version 5.11 (unable to upgrade due to limitations around the software on this server.

There is a specific command for our Veritas Cluster Service that should not be impacting but when our cluster isn't frozen it has been known to cause failovers.

The command in question is vxconfigd.

I'm looking for a way to trigger a query anytime any user runs vxconfigd that holds on running the command and first presents a yes/no question to ask if the cluster resources are frozen.

If it was an in house execute I would just modify the script itself but since it's vendor I don't want to modify it directly.  Which is why I'm looking for something OS level that will do the same.

The only thing I can think of is something with aliasing but that's not very elegant so I'm wondering what other options I have.

Answer (score 2):

Move `vxconfigd` to `real-vxconfigd`.

Create a script `vxconfigd` that asks whether to run the program and then execs `real-vxconfigd`.

Comment: Potentially, the script could check if resources were frozen without prompting the user.

Comment: There's a thought... 

I'll look into whether or not our future patching will cause issues with renaming the script.

Comment: I could just do some aliasing to call the other script instead though...